# Handing errors i.e., 401, 403, etc. for Ember Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js

Searching for suggestions on handling errors in an Ember test? Found a closed issue from last year, [Allowing rejected promises in tests](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11469), which indicated that rejections cannot be conveniently handled. Is this still the case?

Right now, in our application, we are using ajax errors to return an unauthorized error if the user is logged out of our main Rails application.

**Route**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import {isUnauthorizedError, isForbiddenError} from 'ember-ajax/errors';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  userService: Ember.inject.service('user'),

  activate: function(){

    this.get('userService').facility().then(
      (data) => {
        this.get('controller').set('facility', data.data);
      }, (response) => {
        if (isUnauthorizedError(response)) {
          this.transitionTo('report.failure.401');
        } else if (isForbiddenError(response)) {
          this.transitionTo('report.failure.403');
        } else {
        }
      }
    ),
```

**Acceptance Test**

```
test('generates 401 error', function(assert) {
  visit('/reporting');

  httpStubs.stubUser(server, {}, 401);
  httpStubs.stubFacility(server, {});

  httpStubs.stubReport(server, '/api/reports/summary.json', []);
  click('button.btn-filter')

  andThen(function(){
    assert.equal(currentURL(), '/users/login');
  });
```

**Report Stub**

```
  stubReport(server, url, data, status) {
    let statusCode = (status) ? status : 200;

    server.get(url, function() {

      return [
        statusCode,
        {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        JSON.stringify(data)
      ];
    });
  }
```